# Arango Benchmarking - Arango & couchDB

Tags: couchdb, arangodb

What is the concurrency part of the graph? Number of threads? Concurrent Calls?

[Test results for benchmarking ArangoDB and CouchDB](https://web.archive.org/web/20120831155857/https://www.arangodb.org/2012/08/24/benchmarking-arangodb-and-couchdb)

I'm trying to come close to the higher numbers, but not sure how to mimic the concurrency part. My couchDB numbers are always crazy high. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the number of simultaneous client connections used to run the tests. The client is httpress (https://bitbucket.org/yarosla/httpress/wiki/Home):

```
httpress <options> <url>
  -n num   number of requests     (default: 1)
  -t num   number of threads      (default: 1)
  -c num   concurrent connections (default: 1)
  -k       keep alive             (default: no)
  -z pri   GNUTLS cipher priority (default: NORMAL)
  -h       show this help
```

The concurrency refers to the concurrent connections given as "-c" parameter for httpress.